# How do I check if a goroutine is created successfully?

Tags: go, creation, goroutine

In Go, `go` is the keyword to spawn a goroutine. However, it seems the keyword doesn't return any value, so how could I detect if the goroutine is spawned correctly?

It seems Go uses the following ways to check whether a func is successful or not.

```
value, err = myFunc(value)
```

Is there a similar usage for the `go` keyword to detect a creation error? It seems `go` will throw a runtime exception if it failed.

I want to make a test to find out the maximum number of goroutine I could create for a CPU.

Comment: Your question implies that spawning a new goroutine can fail and actually does fail sometimes. What makes you think this assumption is true? Sure, anything can fail (just unplug your CPU or your RAM), but under such conditions you won't be able to check for such troubles. To me your question seems like asking "How to check if `a += 1` was successful?"

Comment: @Volker there is an upper limit to how many goroutines you can have at a given time. It's actually not that hard to even estimate that upper limit.

Comment: Volkerless, I thinks the case is different to "a+=1". Image a game server, the connection from client to server is a long time connection, so need to maintain each state of the client, and the goroutine has its own stack which could shink or grow, so the maximum online game users is limited to the total memory usage of the goroutine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already know:

`value, err = myFunc(value)`

is the idiomatic way to handle exceptions by returning the built-in `error` type. In a way you can compare it to a checked exception, I guess. In your case though, failing to spawn a new `goroutine` is more of a runtime exception. How golang handles those is by using [panics](http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover). You can handle them in your code with the built-in `recover()` function, which will try to regain control of the execution flow. Without that the `panic` will go up the stack until it crashes the program.

Notice that `recover()` has to be called in a function which is being `defer`ed, those functions are pushed into a list and are always called at the end of the function in which they were defered - so even when the `panic` occurs they will be called, allowing you to call `recover()`. If you just try to call `recover()` at the end of your function (or well anywhere after you panicking subfunction) the execution will never reach it. If you can handle the panic (`recover()` doesn't return an `err`) so that your program can actually continue it will execute from the point where the function that threw the panic was.

Think the above blog post is enough but if you need more examples just comment here.

Also your system will most probably be bounded by RAM memory rather than CPU.

Comment: thanks for your answer. so there is other best practice for detect "go" keyword failed instead of a runtime exception? because in C, malloc/free this kind of running out of memory will not throw an exception but a NULL pointer.

Comment: @python you really can't do that, if you're extremely paranoid then you could add a lot of defers like [`this`](http://play.golang.org/p/VQWh7yozKx) but you really shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Another angle: `go` just allocates a little stack segment of a few KB and does some stuff in the scheduler. If you can't allocate a few KB or the space for the scheduler control structures, your program is really, really hosed; that's the kind of condition that's only practical to prevent, not recover from.

Comment: twotwotwo, thanks. It seems go's target is not to be a fully cross platform language, the operation "go" primitive is too high level. If it wants to run on some ARM architecture with limited resources, the memory should be taken into consideration.

Comment: @python That's partially right. Go programs assume you have a couple of megabytes of RAM. There is an ARM port though.

Comment: Yeah, C (or Rust) can certainly fit in very small embedded apps where Go just couldn't. But people do have Go working on [the Raspberry Pi](http://dave.cheney.net/2012/09/25/installing-go-on-the-raspberry-pi) and [an ARM-based backup gadget](https://www.spacemonkey.com/blog/posts/go-space-monkey) and [an Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.camlistore&hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

A goroutine creation is (more or less) just a memory allocation. You cannot in general catch memory allocation exceptions and it's the same with goroutines.

If your program runs out of memory, there's usually nothing you can do about it beyond quitting and restarting.

Comment: hi rog, it sounds reasonable if goroutine could return some value to the caller in case it fails, just like C++ new/malloc, which usually return a NULL pointer in stead of throw out an exception. If a golang game server wants to hold all connection of the user, it sounds reasonable return something if "go" failed

Comment: Why should the "go" statement be special? There are many other places that allocate implicitly. For example assigning a string to an interface{} does an allocation - how could that return an value? Calling a function can allocate too (stacks frames are allocated). We don't want Go to be like C, where you need to check every allocation.

What do you want your test to tell you?

Answer (score 0):

If the function you are using a go routine that returns an error, you can instead call go on an anonymous function and handle the error in the anonymous function.

```
go func() {
    value, err := myFunc()
}()
```